# Android image drawn clipped

Tags: android, drawing, clipping

My question is: I've a relative layout that contains a view (`custom view`). In custom view onDraw `I draw an image bigger than the view size` and I center it. My problem is that the image is clipped on top and the left side so when I perform a `right pan or a down pan` I cannot see the image because it's clipped.

Do you know why?

I find Clip Children but if I set it to true the left and top border are spread on the view during panning.

Thanks

Comment: None can suggest something?

Comment: I was able to solve it simply adding a Parent invalidate.